# Obfuscated AES decryption assembly

Tags: assembly, encryption, arm, aes, reverse-engineering

I have recently been sifting my way through a whole load of assembly to try to identify how a program is decrypting some data. Thus far I have identified how the IV is extracted, that the IV is 16 bytes long and that the decryption method uses Cipher Block Chaining. Consequently I believe that the encryption method being used is AES-128-CBC.

The next step has been to try to identify the key being used to decrypt with, the issue is that the assembly for the individual block cipher encryption is about 2.5MB in size. However, what I have observed is that it is all of a very similar form, for example, a snippet:

```
add.w      r0, r12, #0x13
str.w      r0, [lr, #0x44]
tst.w      r0, #0xff
mov        r0, r12
it         eq
eoreq      r0, r12, #0x75

add.w      r1, r12, #0x5d
str.w      r1, [sp, #0xf00]
tst.w      r1, #0xff
it         eq
addeq      r0, #0x3b
```

`r12` contains the encrypted data, loaded from a passed in argument (`r0`) as follows:

```
mov        r4, r0
add.w      lr, sp, #0x1000
ldrb.w     r12, [r4]
```

All of the assembly in the subroutine is of the exemplar form, some offset is added to the encrypted data, stored, tested against `0xff` (**always** **`0xff`**) and then some operation is performed as a result, either XOR, OR, ADD or MOV affecting another register (in the examples that is `r0`).

Does this look AES-128 to you and do you agree the encryption been deliberately obfuscated to hide the key? If so then how has it been obfuscated and would it be possible to find the key?

**Additional info**

[Here's a link](https://mega.nz/#!IQ5xVIgI!M4dY1QVWPC9fo6zW9aReTKbLMNz-QXbNsAghom6eL7Q) to the full ASM file for the block cipher encryption subroutine.

And [this is a link](https://gist.github.com/SquaredTiki/27f1c24c3f5b0f4743c0) to the subroutine that uses CBC and calls the above subroutine referenced in the main question.

Comment: I think [tag:reverse-engineering] applies more than [tag:security] but feel free to revert this. We really need the architecture tag, however. PS: I am usually quick to downvote but it wasn't me this time ;)

Comment: @Jester Sounds good to me. You've cleared your name :P If it's off-topic/broad for SO I could always move it to the reverse engineering or security SE.

Comment: I don't understand how you have concluded this is CBC-AES, lets say that's the case. But the whole point of AES is that the key can't be broken even if the method is known. AES doesn't need obfuscation.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani The conclusion was based upon the IV size, use of CBC (in another procedure), and internal symbols within the binary referencing AES. The program is decrypting some data therefore the key has to be stored somewhere, no?

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes if it saves the key then it basically boils down to obfuscation.

Comment: @Jester I didn't downvote but I have noticed that someone pretty much downvotes every question that can be remotely seen as _exploiting_ code for nefarious purposes. I think someone even made a meta post about such downvotes. Whether it is same person, maybe not but could have same viewpoint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: You'd expect repetition if the AES implementation has unrolled rounds. This is likely as that can be used to speed up the algorithm.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I see, when you say unrolled do you mean that the key scheduling and all of the AES rounds are directly written in assembly without the use of any loops? If this is the case then would I be correct in assuming the key should be somewhere towards the end of the algorithm as it would be applied last in decryption?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But is the original key not used in the first round (of encryption that is)?

Comment: Sorry. Yes you are right about the key. Step 1 on the expanded key is to use the org key value.

Comment: You'd also expect to see the [Rjindael sbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) accessed either directly or indirectly if they are indeed using AES.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That makes sense, so presumably during decryption the original key value would be applied (XOR'd) last? Do you have any thoughts on whereabouts in the assembly the original key/expanded keys (or part thereof) are defined?

Comment: @planetbeing That's true, I'll read more into that as I've mainly been looking  at the overall process and that of key scheduling so far.

Comment: The snippet you gave essentially does if(ciphertext_byte == 0xED) r0 = 0x98 else r0 = ciphertext_byte; if(ciphertext_byte == 0xa3) r0 += 0x3b;. That part doesn't seem like AES to me at all. It could be just obfuscation or it's doing AddRoundKeys in an extremely obfuscated way (with basically an if for each potential ciphertext byte value). We'd need more of the code to see.

Comment: @planetbeing Agreed, looks like that to me too. Here's a larger snippet but not in full as the assembly file is 60MB: https://gist.github.com/SquaredTiki/3374ecaad9b485f3c19e

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely simple to check whether AES is being used.
AES/Rijndael uses a large table of magical constants.
Without those magic numbers AES cannot work.
You can easily glean these numbers from any reference implementation; remember to compensate for big/little endian if needed (I always check both variants).

Also Rijndael is a very heavy user of the `XOR` instruction, it does not use `or` and it does not use addition.

If you want to confirm/rule out AES, look for the magical numbers. The routine has to read the numbers from a table somewhere in memory (disk). It cannot decode the numbers in the assembly because it uses the plaintext/ciphertext to lookup numbers in an array and xor data with that.

You can't do that when holding the numbers in registers.

From what I can see just looking at the assembly it does not look like AES at all.

**Test AES using code review only**
Perhaps the best test for AES, looking at code only, is to compare it against the reference implementation of `init_key`. AES uses particular code to initialize the secret key so it can be used by the algorithm.

You can find the AES reference source code here: https://tls.mbed.org/aes-source-code
*(Or just about anywhere on the internet if you prefer another language to C).*